# Replace attribute value in XML document

Tags: xml, attributes, xslt-2.0

I have below XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Wrapper>
        <DynamicEnrichment>
            <outpath>/opt/oracle/archive</outpath>
        </DynamicEnrichment>
        <ImagedDocuments sequence="11" beginTime="2018-12-03T16:03:11.7237883-06:00" endTime="2018-12-03T16:03:11.7237883-06:00">
            <Document type="Secure - New Business Reg 60 Disclosure Form" path="\\prdausrvs01\Transfer\Onbase\OUT\EnterprisePrint\b726e5d73692463da29bd9183d6c3b6e_AV001220207.TIF" fileName="REG60DISC"/>
            <Document type="Secure - New Business Reg 60 Disclosure Form1" path="\\prdausrvs01\Transfer\Onbase\OUT\EnterprisePrint\b726e5d73692463da29bd9183d6c3b6e_AV001220204.TIF" fileName="REG60DISC1"/>
        </ImagedDocuments>
    </Wrapper>
```

What I want to do is replace the value "\prdausrvs01\Transfer\Onbase\OUT\EnterprisePrint\" with "/opt/oracle/archive/"

I tried this with below xslt but didn't get the right result.

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <xsl:param name="search" select="substring-before(/Wrapper/ImagedDocuments/Document[1]/@path,'EnterprisePrint')"/>
        <xsl:param name="replace" select="/Wrapper/DynamicEnrichment/outpath"/> 
        <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="@*">
            <xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:text>
            <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="{$search}">           
                <xsl:matching-substring>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$replace"/>
                </xsl:matching-substring>
                <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:non-matching-substring>
            </xsl:analyze-string>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: So which value exactly do you need to replace, how would the result look afterwards? In your text you show a string literal `"\prdausrvs01\Transfer\Onbase\OUT\EnterprisePrint\"`, yet in your code you are trying to use `substring-before(/Wrapper/ImagedDocuments/Document[1]/@path,'EnterprisePrint')` which would certainly not compute the string `\prdausrvs01\Transfer\Onbase\OUT\EnterprisePrint\` but rather `\\prdausrvs01\Transfer\Onbase\OUT\`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reduce the `search` and the `replace` strings to its bare base string and put the `substring...` in the template.

So modify the `xsl:analyze-string` template as follows:

```
<xsl:param name="search" select="'EnterprisePrint\\'"/>
<xsl:param name="replace" select="'/Wrapper/DynamicEnrichment/outpath/'"/>

...

<xsl:template match="@path">
    <xsl:attribute name="path">
        <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="(.*){$search}(.*)">           
            <xsl:matching-substring>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat($replace,regex-group(2))"/>
            </xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:non-matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

---

You also have the alternative possibility of using `xsl:choose` instead of `xsl:analyze-string` (Pay attention to one less slash in the search string):

```
<xsl:param name="search" select="'EnterprisePrint\'"/>
<xsl:param name="replace" select="'/Wrapper/DynamicEnrichment/outpath/'"/>

...

<xsl:template match="@path">
    <xsl:variable name="str" select="substring-before(.,$search)" />
    <xsl:attribute name="path">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$str=''">
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat($replace,substring-after(.,$search))" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

Both version have the same output.

Comment: It worked perfectly. But, I got another requirement that my xslt should get a new element as output so I tried adding below code to it. It now creates only output block  of XML but the existing blocks are not modified at all.

<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:element name='DynamicEnrichment'>
<xsl:attribute name='type'>
<xsl:text>TiffPathModifier</xsl:text>
</xsl:attribute>
<xsl:element name='PreditorEnvironment'>
<xsl:text>Changed TiffPaths if existed</xsl:text>
</xsl:element>   
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

Comment: If my solution did fulfill your needs, please accept it, as this is custom on StackOverflow. And if you have a new question, please create a new [mcve].

Comment: I did create below question. Answer to that would be very much appreciated

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53948731/xslt-to-modify-attribute-value-and-add-new-element