# XSLT to modify attribute value and add new element

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I have below XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Wrapper>
        <DynamicEnrichment>
            <outpath>/opt/oracle/archive</outpath>
        </DynamicEnrichment>
        <ImagedDocuments sequence="11" beginTime="2018-12-03T16:03:11.7237883-06:00" endTime="2018-12-03T16:03:11.7237883-06:00">
            <Document type="Secure - New Business Reg 60 Disclosure Form" path="\\prdausrvs01\Transfer\Onbase\OUT\EnterprisePrint\b726e5d73692463da29bd9183d6c3b6e_AV001220207.TIF" fileName="REG60DISC"/>
            <Document type="Secure - New Business Reg 60 Disclosure Form1" path="\\prdausrvs01\Transfer\Onbase\OUT\EnterprisePrint\b726e5d73692463da29bd9183d6c3b6e_AV001220204.TIF" fileName="REG60DISC1"/>
        </ImagedDocuments>
    </Wrapper>
```

What I want to do is replace the value "\prdausrvs01\Transfer\Onbase\OUT\EnterprisePrint\" with "/opt/oracle/archive/"

I tried this with below xslt but this is outputting only the new element. Existing attribute is not changed.

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <xsl:param name="search" select="'EnterprisePrint\'"/>
        <xsl:param name="replace" select="/Wrapper/DynamicEnrichment/outpath" />
        <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="@path">
            <xsl:variable name="str" select="substring-before(.,$search)" />
            <xsl:attribute name="path">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$str=''">
                        <xsl:value-of select="." />
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat($replace,substring-after(.,$search))" />
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:template> 
        <xsl:template match="/">
            <xsl:element name='DynamicEnrichment'>
                <xsl:attribute name='type'>
                    <xsl:text>TiffPathModifier</xsl:text>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:element name='PreditorEnvironment'>
                    <xsl:text>Changed TiffPaths if existed</xsl:text>
                </xsl:element>          
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:template> 
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: I answered the part of your question how to replace the substring `\prdausrvs01\Transfer\Onbase\OUT\EnterprisePrint\` with `/opt/oracle/archive/` in my preceding answer. What was wrong with it? I apologize if my question seems to be redundant.

Comment: I need to have a new element added along with the replace of attribute value. With above code, its creating a new element only.

Comment: One error you have made is that you have removed the quotes `'` surrounding the `<xsl:param name="replace" select="..."` /_> expression. Both  `xsl:param` have the same format. So change it to `<xsl:param name="replace" select="'/Wrapper/DynamicEnrichment/outpath/'" />`.

Comment: I removed quotes because I wanted the select value to be xpath and not literal.

Comment: You shouldn't have done that, because it compromises the whole code. The single quotes `'` were necessary to create a string value. If you would have passed a string value as parameter to the XSLT, the quotes would have been added automatically. So, keep in mind that these single quotes were essential to my answer. To pass an _XPath expression_ via a parameter to XSLT code you need the XPath-3.0 function [`evaluate`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#evaluate-effect). I guess that this is what you wanted, but it's complicated...

Comment: The ["examples of xsl:evaluate"](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#element-evaluate) may guide you.

Comment: I can add the single quote again if required. No issues with that. 

Basically I want two steps executed by this xslt
1. Change the attribute value
2. Add an element saying its done

Now, when I ran my xslt, if I add both steps, it creates output for only 2nd. If remove this code to add extra element, it would execute fine

Comment: I just checked your code with some new code composed by your specifications. It seems to work fine. I am unable to reproduce your problem. But your `<xsl:template match="/">` seems to be out of order.

Comment: Could you provide your code